# Windows Mobile off topic?

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation, moderators

First, I have a question about an obsolete, un-updated software [here](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/14564/nr-deluxe-support-or-alternitives)

Now to the point, the Area 51 Proposal [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20757/windows-phone) says that it was to be a:

> Beta Q&A site for enthusiasts and power users of Windows Mobile and Windows Phone 7

But my question stated above has been put `On-Hold` for being `Off-Topic` because Windows Mobile is no longer supported and the proposal was years ago.

I know that this topic has been brought up in the past, but none that I have read have much to back them up, especially not the proposal on Area 51.

There are many people that have used Windows Mobile, and a few, like me, still use it.

Also there are no questions before that have been answered with a consistent, some what unanimous, agreed upon answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Windows Mobile on topic?](http://meta.windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/13/is-windows-mobile-on-topic)

Comment: @User5, I reverenced similar questions, I'm wanting this to be the Final answer, as there is still some confusion, and none really address the issue of it originally being proposed for this site. I believe It should still be on topic as It is still technically a windows phone. And people still answer questions about XP on SuperUser, Why not Windows Mobile questions here

Comment: I am also a bit confused about it therefore gavethis link. If I were sure, I would have taken part in the discussion.

Comment: it's also a topic that has come up multiple times in the past, but, like I said earlier, nobody brought up that it's was this community was made for.

Comment: If I don't start getting answers soon, I'm asking it out side of this meta, where everyone can answer, and If I  still don't get anything, stack exchange meta

Comment: Well whatsoever.....Windows mobile is dead, but should not be disown so rudely.

Comment: I have a Palm Treo 700wx, I am for WM being on-topic and I like it more than android (barely if only it had more apps)

Comment: @DanHolli: Palm OS has a [still-active sub-Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Palm). Maybe Windows Mobile does too? I dunno.